# md5sum not matching python generated md5

Tags: python, linux, file, hash, md5

I have this bizarre problem where my md5 hash from a streamed file does not match `md5sum`. The weird thing is if I read the file in and write it out to a second file, the python md5 and `md5sum second_file.txt` agree. Here's the hash code:

```
import hashlib 
import sys

file_hash = hashlib.md5()
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f, open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as w:
    while True:
        c = f.read(1)
        w.write(c)
        file_hash.update(c.encode(encoding='utf-8'))

        if c == '':
            # end of file
            break

print(file_hash.hexdigest())
```

Both files are in `UTF-8` and running in a docker container. I'm kind of at a loss here. Any ideas?

Comment: you are not showing the streamed bit ... so its unlikely anyone will be able to definitively answer. .. but at a guess its an encoding issue (ie streamed files are usually bytes... but you are opening the file in "r" mode not "rb" ... maybe try opening the file with "rb" and dont do the encode bit

Comment: updated & trying now

Comment: at a guess the file your opening is already utf8 and it matches the stream after you write it because python will save the file as utf8 ... but i dont know that the file is streamed with utf8

Comment: calling the `hash.py` script on the second file will result in a hash that agrees with `md5sum`. It's just the original file that's giving me different results.

Comment: to check sameness you could load them into `bytearray` and look at the int values of the bytes and compare them... basically im 99% sure you have some sort of encoding/decoding  issue... that cannot be reasonably trouble shot without seeing the exact data you are dealing with or a near enough facimile to be reproducible

Comment: Fair enough. Let me try to generate something that is reproducible but I suspect it's how the original file was written.

Comment: @JoranBeasley reading in the file with `rb` fixed the issue. Thanks for the help! If you'd like to leave an answer I'll select it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open the file in `"rb"` mode to get the raw bytes, and skip the `encode` bit ... you are effectively changing the bytes that md5 is comparing when doing this

Answer (score 1):

In general the problem could be python or the md5sum function from linux, hence it would be preferred if you provide the linux command line that shows the different hashes. In my experience this most likely happens when one attempts pipe from "echo" but forgets that "echo" adds a newline character to whatever it echo's.

For example, these DO NOT match:

```
>> echo 'thing' | md5sum
>> python -c "import hashlib;print(hashlib.md5(b'thing').hexdigest())"
```

Use "printf" to prevent the newline from being added. These DO match:

```
>> printf 'thing' | md5sum
>> python -c "import hashlib;print(hashlib.md5(b'thing').hexdigest())"
```

You can also place the data in a file:

```
>> printf 'thing' > temp
>> cat temp | md5sum
>> python -c "import hashlib;print(hashlib.md5(b'thing').hexdigest())"
```